# Filter the object in the array by dynamic filter - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope

Right now my data structure is like

```
product = [{att1:'2',att2:'red',att3:'gold'},
    {att1:'1',att2:'blue',att3:'wood'},
    {att1:'2',att2:'green',att3:'plastic'},
    {att1:'1',att2:'red',att3:'plastic'}]
```

And I have a filter on the web page, it has three parts: att1, att2, att3. The user doesn't have to choose options for every part.

- For filter att1 it has 2 options: "1" and "2".
- Filter att2 it has 2 options: "red" "blue" and "green"
- Filter att3 it has 3 options: "gold", "wood" and "plastic".

I can get the options that are selected. For example:
`{att1:['2'],att3:['gold','plastic']}` or `{att1:['1']}`

My question is, how do I use `product.filter` to filter the product data?
Thanks!

Comment: please format your question

Comment: Are you looking for how to write a custom $filter or are you trying to use the array filter function? not really clear what's being asked here or where you're stuck.

Comment: @shaunhusain  The situation is sometimes the user chooses the option under `att1` sometimes not. So filter function cannot use hard code to filter product data because it may return `att1==='1'` or `att1==='1' && att2==='red'` or `(att1==='1'|| att1==='2') && (att2==='green' || att2==='red') && att3==='gold'` sometime, it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom filter function which is easy to use, I used `att1` but you can expand it to all fields:

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{att1:'2',att2:'red',att3:'gold'},
    {att1:'1',att2:'blue',att3:'wood'},
    {att1:'2',att2:'green',att3:'plastic'},
    {att1:'1',att2:'red',att3:'plastic'}];

  $scope.filterFunction = function(element) {
    return element.att1.match(/^Ma/) ? true : false;
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input ng-model="query" type="text"
        placeholder="Filter by" autofocus>
    </form>
    <ul ng-repeat="product in products | filter:query">
      <li>{{product}}</li>
    </ul>
    
    
    <ul ng-repeat="product in products | filter:filterFunction">
      <li>{{product}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: filterFunction defined but not referenced?

Comment: oh, my bad, fixed now @shaunhusain

Comment: All good just to add to this could use the filter function like `angular.filter('productFilter', function(){ return function filterFunction(input, arg){/*your  filtering code returns a new array with the filtered values*/}})` then use it like `product in products | productFilter` https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters you can also retrieve any filter functions using the $filter service like `var prodFilterFn = $filter('productFilter');`

Comment: @Yaser Thanks! But the situation is sometimes the user chooses the option under att1 sometimes not. So `$scope.filterFunction` in your code cannot use hard code to filter product data by `att1` because it may return `att1.match` or `att1.match && att2.mach` or `(att1.match || att1.match) && (att2.match || att2.match) && att3.match` sometime, it's dynamic, how do I solve this?

Comment: This was just an example, you will need to change the filter function logic to contain whatever scenario that may happen from user inputs, if you have a fiddle or something maybe that would help to get a clearer picture of your situation @molly12345

Answer (score 0):

I banged out the particular logic for this one, using the three nested loops isn't super great but it does do the job.  I'm sure you can optimize this further by using some maps or something but I just went with the get it done by brute force approach :)

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .service('ProductService', function(){  
    return {
      products:[
        {att1:'2',att2:'red',att3:'gold'},
        {att1:'1',att2:'blue',att3:'wood'},
        {att1:'2',att2:'green',att3:'plastic'},
        {att1:'1',att2:'red',att3:'plastic'}
      ]
    }
  })
  
  .controller('TestCtrl', function(ProductService){
    this.ProductService = ProductService;
    this.filterObject1 = {att1:['2'],att3:['gold','plastic']};
    this.filterObject2 = {att1:['1']};
  })
  
  .filter('productFilter', function(){
    return function(input,filterObj){
      if(!filterObj){
        return input;
      }
      var newArray = [];
      var filterKeys = Object.keys(filterObj);
      
      for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        var curElement = input[i];
        innerLoops:
        for(var j=0;j<filterKeys.length;j++){
          var curKey= filterKeys[j];
          for(var k=0;k<filterObj[curKey].length;k++){
            var curFilterValue = filterObj[curKey][k];
            if(curElement[curKey].match(curFilterValue)){
              //We found a match keep this element and move on to checking the next one by breaking out of the inner loops that are checking particular keys/values
              newArray.push(curElement);
              break innerLoops;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return newArray;
    };
  })
  ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl">
Unfiltered
  <div ng-repeat="product in ctrl.ProductService.products|productFilter">
    {{product}}
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <strong>Filtered with: {{ctrl.filterObject1}}</strong>
  <div ng-repeat="product in ctrl.ProductService.products|productFilter:ctrl.filterObject1">
    {{product}}
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <strong>Filtered with {{ctrl.filterObject2}}</strong>
  <div ng-repeat="product in ctrl.ProductService.products|productFilter:ctrl.filterObject2">
    {{product}}
  </div>
</div>
```